# displaying image on android from the path provided in webservice response xml

Tags: android, web-services

From Android, I am consuming a REST Web Service using HttpURLConnection, InputStream and xmlFactoryObject. I am receiving response as mentioned below

RESPONSE XML from WebService:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<employees>
    <employee>
        <empId>123</empId>
        <empName>asd</empName>
        <ext>asdas</ext>
        <location>asdasd</location>
        <photoPath>D:\PhotoPath\asd.gif</photoPath>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

After parsing the above response xml, I receive photopath as D:\PhotoPath\asd.gif.

How to display this image in Android Image View? Is it problem with Service as photopath mentioned is relative to server where my web service is hosted. If so how to handle it?

Comment: What do you mean by  `D` in  `D:\PhotoPath\asd.gif`

Answer (score 0):

The above path you have obtained in  the response is wrong. You will have to create a virtual directory in your server path. so you image path will appear something as follow : www.yourdomain.com/PhotoPath/asd.gif. You can then show this image on imageview using some library like AQuery

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
URL url = new URL("your image url");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

where `imageView` is your ImageView
 You can otherwise use any library like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Pass url and imageview object to displayImage method.It will load images by caching it.So next time you will not need to download same image
package com.fudiyo.images;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.fudiyo.R;
import com.fudiyo.config.Config;
import com.fudiyo.twitter.ScaleBitmap;

public class ImageLoader {

    // Initialize MemoryCache
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();

    FileCache fileCache;

    Context C;

    // Create Map (collection) to store image and image url in key value pair
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;

    // handler to display images in UI thread
    Handler handler = new Handler();

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {

        C = context;
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);

        // Creates a thread pool that reuses a fixed number of
        // threads operating off a shared unbounded queue.
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    }

    // default image show in list (Before online image download)
    final int stub_id = R.drawable.fudiyo_default;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView, Context context,
            boolean header_flag) {

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.fudiyo_default);

        // Store image and url in Map
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

        // Check image is stored in MemoryCache Map or not (see
        // MemoryCache.java)
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            // if image is stored in MemoryCache Map then
            // Show image in listview row
            Bitmap b = ScaleBitmap
                    .getScaledBitmap(context, bitmap, header_flag);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);

        } else {
            // queue Photo to download from url
            queuePhoto(url, imageView, header_flag);

            // Before downloading image show default image
            imageView.setImageBitmap( ScaleBitmap
                    .getScaledBitmap(context, largeIcon, header_flag));

        }
    }
    public void DisplayRoundedImage(String url, ImageView imageView, Context context,
            boolean header_flag) {

        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                R.drawable.defaultuserphoto);

        // Store image and url in Map
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);

        // Check image is stored in MemoryCache Map or not (see
        // MemoryCache.java)
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);

        if (bitmap != null) {
            // if image is stored in MemoryCache Map then
            // Show image in listview row
            Bitmap b = ScaleBitmap
                    .getScaledRoundedBitmap(context, bitmap, header_flag);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(b);

        } else {
            // queue Photo to download from url
            queuePhoto(url, imageView, header_flag);

            // Before downloading image show default image
            imageView.setImageBitmap( ScaleBitmap
                    .getScaledRoundedBitmap(context, largeIcon, header_flag));

        }
    }


    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView, boolean header_flag) {
        // Store image and url in PhotoToLoad object
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView, header_flag);

        // pass PhotoToLoad object to PhotosLoader runnable class
        // and submit PhotosLoader runnable to executers to run runnable
        // Submits a PhotosLoader runnable task for execution

        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public boolean b;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i, boolean header_flag) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
            b = header_flag;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                // Check if image already downloaded
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                // download image from web url
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);

                // set image data in Memory Cache
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);

                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;

                // Get bitmap to display
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);

                // Causes the Runnable bd (BitmapDisplayer) to be added to the
                // message queue.
                // The runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler
                // is attached.
                // BitmapDisplayer run method will call
                handler.post(bd);

            } catch (Throwable th) {
                // th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        // CHECK : if trying to decode file which not exist in cache return null
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // Download image file from web
        try {

            // // download the image
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            URL imageURL = null;
            try {

                imageURL = new URL(
                        Config.WEB_URL+"/ServeBlob?id=" + url);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) imageURL
                        .openConnection();
                connection.setDoInput(true);
                connection.connect();
                // if(!(new File(imageURL.toString())).exists())
                // {
                // imageURL=new URL("");
                // }
                InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

                // Constructs a new FileOutputStream that writes to
                // file
                // if file not exist then it will create file
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);

                // See Utils class CopyStream method
                // It will each pixel from input stream and
                // write pixels to output stream (file)
                Utils.CopyStream(inputStream, os);

                os.close();

                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                options.inSampleSize = 8;

                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                // e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Now file created and going to resize file with defined height
            // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);

            return bitmap;

        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {

        try {

            // Decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.

            // Set width/height of recreated image
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 85;

            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with current scale values
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {

        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        // Check url is already exist in imageViews MAP
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            // Show bitmap on UI
            if (bitmap != null) {
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(ScaleBitmap
                        .getScaledBitmap(C, bitmap, photoToLoad.b));
            } else {

            }
            // photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        // Clear cache directory downloaded images and stored data in maps
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }

}







package com.fudiyo.images;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;

public class MemoryCache {

    private static final String TAG = "MemoryCache";

    //Last argument true for LRU ordering
    private Map<String, Bitmap> cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(
            new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(10,1.5f,true));

   //current allocated size
    private long size=0; 

    //max memory cache folder used to download images in bytes
    private long limit = 1000000; 

    public MemoryCache(){

        //use 25% of available heap size
        setLimit(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()/4);
    }

    public void setLimit(long new_limit){

        limit=new_limit;
        Log.i(TAG, "MemoryCache will use up to "+limit/1024./1024.+"MB");
    }

    public Bitmap get(String id){
        try{
            if(!cache.containsKey(id))
                return null;
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            return cache.get(id);
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public void put(String id, Bitmap bitmap){
        try{
            if(cache.containsKey(id))
                size-=getSizeInBytes(cache.get(id));
            cache.put(id, bitmap);
            size+=getSizeInBytes(bitmap);
            checkSize();
        }catch(Throwable th){
            th.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void checkSize() {
        Log.i(TAG, "cache size="+size+" length="+cache.size());
        if(size>limit){
            Iterator<Entry<String, Bitmap>> iter=cache.entrySet().iterator();//least recently accessed item will be the first one iterated  
            while(iter.hasNext()){
                Entry<String, Bitmap> entry=iter.next();
                size-=getSizeInBytes(entry.getValue());
                iter.remove();
                if(size<=limit)
                    break;
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Clean cache. New size "+cache.size());
        }
    }

    public void clear() {
        try{
            //NullPointerException sometimes happen here http://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/issues/detail?id=78 
            cache.clear();
            size=0;
        }catch(NullPointerException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    long getSizeInBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if(bitmap==null)
            return 0;
        return bitmap.getRowBytes() * bitmap.getHeight();
    }
}












package com.fudiyo.images;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Utils {
    public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
    {
        final int buffer_size=1024;
        try
        {

            byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
            for(;;)
            {
              //Read byte from input stream

              int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
              if(count==-1)
                  break;

              //Write byte from output stream
              os.write(bytes, 0, count);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){}
    }
}
```